# кафка консумер перечитывает сообщения, по которым уже закоммичен offset

Tags: golang, apache-kafka

Недавно работаю с кафкой.
Запускаю консумера. прочитаны все сообщения в топике к которому он подключается . Т.е. offset равен количеству сообщений.

Консумер в консоль пишет что нет сообщений для чтения:
no messages received from kafka within the allocated time for partition 0 of topic_name at offset 3

Но в бесконечном цикле, который запускается в консумере , все равно перечитывает все сообщения топика с самого начала.

Это  нормально? как этого не  допускать?

с кафкой работаю на golang. Использую пакет
github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

```
    ...
func consume(ctx context.Context) {
  r := getKafkaReader(brokerAddress, "json-requests")

  // в бесконечном цикле ждем сообщения в топике кафка
  for {
    msg, err := r.ReadMessage(ctx)
    if err != nil {
      panic("consume.could not read message " + err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("consume.received: ", string(msg.Value))
  }
}

// Создаем читателя
func getKafkaReader(kafkaUrl, topicName string) *kafka.Reader {
  l := log.New(os.Stdout, "consume.kafka reader: ", 0)

  brokers := strings.Split(kafkaUrl, ",")
  return kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
    Brokers:    brokers,
    Partition:   0,
    Topic:       topicName,
    MinBytes:    10e3, // 10KB
    MaxBytes:    10e6, // 10MB
    StartOffset: kafka.LastOffset, 
    Logger:    l,  
  })
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился добавлением GroupID
Без указания группы консюмера , игнорируется опция StartOffset